# c++ Can I use std::unique_ptr with dependency injection?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, c++11, unique-ptr

I had been doing dependency injection using raw pointers and I decided to convert my code to use shared_ptr.  This works but I'm wondering if I could use unique_ptr instead?  In my example below, MyClass would manage the lifetime of the credit card service.

```
class PaymentProcessor
{
    PaymentProcessor(?? creditCardService):
      :creditCardService_(creditCardService)
      {

      }

private:
   CreditCardService *creditCardService_;     
}

class MyClass
{ 
public:
   void DoIt()
   {
     creditCardService_.reset(new VisaCardService());
     PaymentProcessor pp(creditCardService_);
     pp.ProcessPayment();
   }

private:   
   std::unique_ptr<CreditCardService> creditCardService_;
}
```

Can you pass a unique_ptr to another class where the other class is just "using" the pointer (without owning it??)?  If so is this a good idea and what should the type of the parameter be in the constructor for PaymentProcessor?

**UPDATE**

In the example as shown above I can alternatively create a `VisaCardService` variable on the stack and have the `PaymentProcessor` constructor take this as a reference parameter. This seems to be the recommended C++ practice.  However, in the case where the concrete type of creditCardService_ is not known until runtime (e.g., the user chooses the particular Credit Card Service to use at runtime), is using `std::unique_ptr` with references the best solution?

Comment: Call the `get()` member function of the unique pointer.

Comment: According to your update: Yes this would be a use-case for a `std::unique_ptr`. But in this case this pointer still doesn't need to be a member variable of the class, if it's only needed inside `DoIt`. You can just make it a local `std::unique_ptr`, with dynamically allocated storage. This way the object gets destroyed as soon as you leave the function, due to `std::unique_ptr`s smart destruction facilities.

Comment: I agree with Christian. Unless you want to somehow cache the service across many calls, your unique_ptr should have the smallest possible scope -- here, the scope of DoIt.

Comment: @BartoszMilewski: agreed.  In my code in fact I need my service across multiple calls.  Here I was trying to keep the example small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you pass a unique_ptr to another class where the other class is
>   just "using" the pointer (without owning it??)?

In that case, change the pointer to reference :

```
class PaymentProcessor
{
public:
    PaymentProcessor(CreditCardService & creditCardService_):
      :creditCardService_(creditCardService_)
      {
      }

private:
   CreditCardService &creditCardService_;     
};

   void DoIt()
   {
     creditCardService_.reset(new VisaCardService());
     PaymentProcessor pp(*creditCardService_);
     pp.ProcessPayment();
   }
```

If you still want to use a pointer, then you need to use `get` method :

```
class PaymentProcessor
{
public:
    PaymentProcessor(CreditCardService * creditCardService_):
      :creditCardService_(creditCardService_)
      {
      }
private:
   CreditCardService *creditCardService_;     
};

   void DoIt()
   {
     creditCardService_.reset(new VisaCardService());
     PaymentProcessor pp(creditCardService_.get());
     pp.ProcessPayment();
   }
```

Comment: I agree, the reference solution is better and more clearly expresses what's going on here.

Comment: Actually, in  the current setup you wouldn't even need dynamic allocation for `MyClass`'s `creditCardService_`, but I guess (or rather hope) the real code is a bit more complex.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I think I would need it in this case because CreditCardService is a base class of VisaCardService.  Or no?

Comment: @User: Nope. You can declare it as a local variable inside the `DoIt` function. `PaymenProcessor` will still need to take a reference to the base class and it all of it's calls to methods will be dynamic still. But in `DoIt` you don't need to use a `unique_ptr` at all with the code you've shown. I expect your real code is more complex though.

Comment: @User You can just make a `VisaCardService` member variable in `MyClass` (without a pointer) or even better, a local `VisaCardService` variable in `DoIt`. Always keep in mind that this is C++, where automatic variables can (and should when possible) be used and that polymorphism doesn't neccessarily imply dynamic allocation. The fact that the `PaymentProcessor` takes a pointer (or better a reference) doesn't imply that this storage needs to be allocated dynamically. But of course, if the real code is more complex than this, you may still require a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: So I can declare VisaCardService as automatic variable on the stack and have PaymentProcessor take a reference to CreditCardService, and then inside PaymentProcessor calls to methods on CreditCardService will polymorphically call VisaCardService overrides?

Comment: @User Yes, of course, as long as the `PaymentProcessor` takes (and stores) a reference or a pointer.

Comment: Aha I see.  So in this case the only use of dynamic allocation would be to change the type dynamically at run-time such as if the actual concrete type chosen depended on some logic or user intervention? In C# I'm used to having variables defined as interfaces or base classes which I figured implied dynamic allocation in C++.

Comment: @User: Basically, yes. Though the reason for dynamic allocation has more to do with variable lifetime. If the logic is such that the lifetime cannot be managed with static scoping and the stack, then you need dynamic allocation.

Comment: @User That's it. Of course there are other use cases, e.g. if the lifetime or the ownership of an object is not bound to a single function or other object or not determinable at compile time. But in your case you're absolutely right. The fact that the so-called "modern" languages tend to ban non-primitive automatic variables doesn't make them unsuited.

Comment: @User: I felt you raised an interesting question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973138/how-do-i-choose-heap-allocation-vs-stack-allocation

Comment: @Omnifarious: Interesting I look forward to seeing the answers

Comment: I wouldn't recomand the second proposed version though because is not clear for PaymentProcessor that it doesn't own passed pointer. The whole ideea of using smart pointers is about managing ownership such that it can't be broken...) at least without a good fight :-)