# C++11 member initializer list vs in-class initializer?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

What difference between these ways of initializing object member variables in C++11 ? Is there another way ?  which way is better (performance) ?:

```
class any {
  public:
    obj s = obj("value");
    any(){}
};
```

Or

```
class any {
  public:
    obj s;
    any(): s("value"){}
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: I agree, they are the same. I just wanted to add that for further reference you can read "The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition" section 17.4.4.

Comment: Very similar to [Has the new C++11 member initialization feature at declaration made initialization lists obsolete?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24149924/1708801)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No, these are **not the same**.

The difference between them is the same that applies for *direct-initialization* vs. *copy-initialization*, which is subtle but often very confusing.

§12.6.2 [class.base.init]:

> 7. The *expression-list* or *braced-init-list* in a *mem-initializer* is used to initialize the designated subobject (or, in the case of a delegating constructor, the complete class object) according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for **direct-initialization.** [...]
> 8. In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or base class is not designated by a *mem-initializer-id* (including the case where there is no *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no *ctor-initializer*) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
>    — if the entity is a non-static data member that has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, the entity is initialized **as specified in 8.5**;

§8.5 [dcl.init]:

> 15. The initialization that occurs in the form
>
>     T x = a;
>
> as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception (15.1), handling an exception (15.3), and aggregate member initialization (8.5.1) **is called copy-initialization**.

Initializing a non-static data member on a *member-initializer-list* follows the rules of *direct-initialization*, which doesn't create intermediate temporaries that need to be moved/copied (if compiled without a *copy-elision*), neither the type of the data member must be copyable/movable (even if the copy is elided). In addition, a *direct-initialization* introduces an explicit context, while a *copy-initialization* is non-explicit (if a constructor selected for the initialization is `explicit`, the program won't compile).

In other words, the `obj s = obj("value");` syntax won't compile if `obj` is declared as:

```
struct obj
{
    obj(std::string) {}
    obj(const obj&) = delete;
};
```

or:

```
struct obj
{
    obj(std::string) {}
    explicit obj(const obj&) {}
};
```

As a more tangible example, while the below won't compile:

```
struct any
{
   std::atomic<int> a = std::atomic<int>(1); // ill-formed: non-copyable/non-movable
   std::atomic<int> b = 2; // ill-formed: explicit constructor selected
};
```

this one will:

```
struct any
{
    std::atomic<int> a;
    std::atomic<int> b{ 2 };
    any() : a(1) {}
};
```

---

> *Which way is better (performance) ?*

With a *copy-elision* enabled both have identical performance. With *copy-elision* disabled, there is an additional copy/move constructor call upon every instantiation when the *copy-initialization* syntax is used (that `obj s = obj("value");` is one of).

---

> *Is there another way ?*

The *brace-or-equal-initializer* syntax allows one to perform a *direct-list-initialization* as well:

```
class any {
public:
    obj s{ "value" };
    any() {}
};
```

---

> *Are there any other differences?*

Some other differences that are worth mentioning are:

1. *Brace-or-equal-initializer* must reside in a header file along with a class declaration.
2. If both are combined, *member-initializer-list* takes priority over *brace-or-equal-initializer* (that is, *brace-or-equal-initializer* is ignored).
3. (C++11 only, until C++14) A class that uses *brace-or-equal-initializer* violates constraints for an aggregate type.
4. With the *brace-or-equal-initializer* syntax it's not possible to perform a *direct-initialization* other than a *direct-list-initialization*.

Comment: Thanks , it seems you  are right :) , I have another question , if I say : obj s{"value"} , it will store in stack ,right ? and when I say : obj *s = new s("value") , it will store in the heap ?? if so , when I need to store in either stack or heap ? can you explain it plz

Comment: @AhmedTajElsir if the object that contains (as a data member) `obj s{"value"}` is allocated on the heap, then `s` will be allocated on the heap as well. Whether you should allocate data members on stack/heap depends on design decisions/further usage of those objects

Comment: can you clarify  "...depends on design decisions/further usage of those objects" .

Comment: @AhmedTajElsir it's too broad subject to write it in a comment, you might find the answer to [How do I choose heap allocation vs. stack allocation in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973138/how-do-i-choose-heap-allocation-vs-stack-allocation-in-c) question very useful, as it's exactly what you ask about

Comment: Could anybody explain what is exactly meant by "violates constraints for an aggregate type" - pont 3. at the end of the article, thanks!

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki , please have a look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634869/is-it-direct-initialization-or-copy-initialization . I would really appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 6):

Both examples are equivalent.
Though only if the type is copyable or movable (check it for yourself) and NRVO is actually done (any halfway decent compiler will do it as a matter of course).

Though if you had many constructors and constructor-chaining were inappropriate, the first method would allow you not to repeat yourself.

Also, you can use that method to define aggregates with defaults different from aggregate-initialization for (some) members since C++14.

Answer (score 5):

They are the same.

Neither is better than the other in terms of performance, and there is no other way to initialise them.

The benefit of in-class initialisation (the first in your example) is that the order of initialisation is implicit. In initialiser list you have to explicitly state the order - and compilers will warn of out-of-order initialisation if you get the ordering incorrect.

From the standard:

```
12.6.2.5
nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they were declared 
in the class definition
```

If you get the order wrong in your list, GCC will complain:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'C::C()':
main.cpp:51:9: warning: 'C::b' will be initialized after
main.cpp:51:6: warning:   'int C::a'
```

The benefit of initialiser lists is perhaps a matter of taste - the list is explicit, typically in the source file. In-class is implicit (arguably), and is typically in the header file.

Comment: No need to state the order in ctor-init-lists, it is always implicit and independent of how you order the initializers.

Comment: Thanks a lot , personally I like first method , because it's familiar (Java programer before :D ) , but I was afraid there is performance difference .